# INSERT INTO & [declaredTABLENAME] & [SQLQUERY]

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Currently, I am working on insert function on my project, and I tried all the logic that will come into my mind, but all those are useless. My Main problem is, there are 2 rows that have identical values inserted into my table. I have two tables in my database access, for example, tbl1 and tbl2.

In tbl1 these are example value and fields.

```
    NAME | MARK | LENGTH
    --------------------
    ALEX | AAAA | 1.25
    ALEX | AAAA | 1.25
    ROAN | RRRR | 1.25
```

And this table should be copied in another table, the example is tbl2.
the field of two tables is the same.

BUT, I want a result like this

```
NAME | MARK | LENGTH
--------------------
ALEX | AAAA | 1.25
            | 1.25

ROAN | RRRR | 1.25
```

AND I have tried the code below.

```
        strSQL = " SELECT * FROM " & tbl1 & " WHERE NAME='" & strname & "'"

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & tbl2 & strSQL
        Call clsRes.ExcuteSQL(strSQL)
```

Any help will be so much appreciated! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Despite the superficial resemblance, SQL tables are *not* the same thing as spreadsheets. Stop trying to do spreadsheet style *presentation* in the database.

Comment: The data that would be inserted in the database will be used in Excel sir. and also my database is MS Access sir.

Comment: How could that be useful in Excel? If you sort rows, the 'blank' row with 1.25 loses its connection to Name and Mark. What @Damien_The_Unbeliever said about SQL applies to MS Access and any other relational database platform. Query cannot do what you want. Build a report and set textbox HideDuplicates property to Yes.

Comment: It can be done via ACCESS REPORT using HideDuplicates Property OR CODING from access VBA, exporting data to excel via grouping method.

Comment: Because the excel is my report sir. that's why

Comment: @AlexisVillar so the solution to that is formatting your MS Access data output to Excel.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @AlexisVillar Post what you had done on your code and we will try to help you.

Comment: I am thinking about recordset sir. Maybe if i get it right with the recordcount inside the table, then if i have filtered it, i will remove the string field with = "". but thanks sir.

Comment: @AlexisVillar you might be talking to a woman

Comment: @the_lotus I have been called many things on SO but I have never been offended by Sir, which is merely a poster's politeness and civility showing.

Comment: I'm sorry @the_lotus